# I just want to query Parity what setup should I use?

Tags: parity

I want to run javascript on node locally against Web3. I require a minimal amount of information security and I just want it to work.

I tried `snap run parity --light` and it is slow because it still needs to sync something.

[image]

I am seeking something about 100x faster. How can I do this?

version Parity/v1.9.7-unstable-7919629-20180423/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.25.0

Answer (score 0):

Everything needs to b synced before u can do anything on the network. SSD's can improve read write speeds